# rsync : Recursively sync multiple file types while ignoring directory structure

Tags: bash, rsync

Is there a way to make `rsync` recursively sync multiple file types but not copy the directory structure, just the files?

So far i have got this

```
  rsync -zarvm --include="*/" --include=*.{xml,properties} --exclude="*" /foo/ /syncdDir/
```

Which this gives me this

```
/foo/
    file1.properties
    dir1/
    dir1/file1.xml
    file2.properties
    dir2/
    dir2/file2.xml
```

What I am looking for is just the `file{1,2}.xml` and `file{1,2}.properties` files copied into the `/syncdDir/`, not the directories `dir1` and `dir2`.

Comment: You could probably wing it with `find` and `rsync`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be able to flatten the structure with `rsync` directly, but you could use `find` to help you do that:

```
find -type f \( -name '*.xml' -o -name '*.properties' \)
    -exec rsync -zarvm {} /syncDir/ \;
```

When you use `find` to do the searching, it's easy to hard-code the output folder to be the same for all inputs.

Comment: Thanks, I got this working by adding parentheses and escaping them with the backslashes

Comment: I've run into a problem with files being open or in use at the time of processing. I know there's a way around it but not sure how to do it. How can I enhance the script to ignore open files at the time of processing?

Comment: @CloseTurkey  That's a separate question.